# How can I get item from a model field

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django beginner, how can I get profile_pic from Profile Model connecting it to 'to_user' field in FriendRequest Model.

I was able to get the names of users in 'to_user' field by this:

```
{% for data in sent_friend_request %}
{{ data.to_user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I get the profile_pic for each users?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField()

class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

def following_view(request, username):
     sent_friend_request = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user__username=username)

context = {'sent_friend_request':sent_friend_request}

{% if data.to_user.profile_pic %} 
<img src="{{ data.to_user.profile_pic }}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You should use `get` instead of `filter` when you expect a single objet to be retrieved from the database (such as the profile `p` here). This way, you avoid these weird for loops that just confuse the reader (and, as a bonus, you get a nice exception if the object does not exist, instead of silently failing).

Comment: function `following_view` is still half baked, as imo it will only send the last user friend request. If you have removed some of your code before posting then please make sure it should look logical

Comment: <img src="{{ data.to_user.profile_pic.url }}">. this will show profile pic. follow all suggestions in comments. all will be helpfull.

Comment: @anuragal I, too, thought that. But `p` should contain a single object anyway…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
{% if data.to_user.profile.profile_pic %} 

<img src="{{ data.to_user.profile.profile_pic.url }}">

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this work in the answer? Especially the default name of the reverse one-to-one relationship.

Comment: @arjun.. This worked. data.to_user.PROFILE.profile_pic.url 'PROFILE' does the magic. Thanks